# Bash script to automate ASP.NET form submittal?

Tags: asp.net, macos, bash, post, curl

**Scenario**: I have an internal ASP.NET site that allows me to maintain a set of rules (CRUD). To add a new rule I simply fill out a HTML form and click submit. My current issue is that I now need to add a few hundred rules and I want to use a script to automate this.

**Initial plan**:

- Create a script that can take X number of arguments and use these to fake a form submittal of the above web page
- Create a comma-separated file (or similar) with one row per rule and each column represents one of the input tags in the HTML form
- Create another script that can use the comma-separated file to execute the form-submittal script once for every row

My attempts has centered around **curl**, and worked well against an [online testing page](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/testing.html). Unfortunately I'm not able to get it to work against the ASP.NET page and I'm guessing this has to do something with Postback and/or Viewstate.

**Snippet**:

```
curl -s -u "DOMAIN\user:password" --ntlm -d "key1=value1" -d "key2=value2" http://internal/page.aspx
```

(Returns the page as if using a GET, no error messages)

**Question**:

How can I trick the ASP page that I'm sending a *Postback*? (alternative scripting suggestions are welcome as well)

**EDIT**:

Snippet from ASP page:

```
<asp:LinkButton ... runat="server" OnClick="lbAddRule_Click" PostBackUrl="~/Page.aspx" />
```

Snippet from code behind:

```
protected void lbAddRule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (Page.IsValid == true) {
    AddRule(x,y,z);
```

Comment: Do you need an actual postback or just a post (this is something you'd be able to check if you have access to the page source)?  A good first stab would be to parse the `ViewState` input field(or fields) from the page and submit those along with your request.  That might be enough to make the page think it's a postback.  Also, if this is pretty straight up CRUD, would it be easier to just insert stuff directly into whatever database backs this application?

Comment: @R0MANARMY I've added code snippets from the web page. Seems my assumption on the "if (Page.IsPostBack)" clause was a little premature, although I didn't get closer to a solution. Unfortunately I do not have access to the database, that would have made scripting a whole lot easier.

Comment: If you really don't want to do this by hand, you could try recording a couple of regular posts using firebug, seeing which variables change (ideally just the fields you want to submit), template the post and submit whatever you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a completely different approach, have you considered scripting the browser itself? There are a few very powerful techniques, including Selenium/WebDriver [1] and iMacros [2], both of which allow this kind of scripting.

[1] http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

[2] http://wiki.imacros.net/Browser_Automation

Comment: Downloaded plugin to Internet Explorer, browsed a few of their demo macros and got it working (pulling data from a CSV file) within an hour. Excellent!

Comment: Sometimes you just need a different approach! Glad it's working.

Answer (score 1):

If this is intended as a RESTful service (which you're accessing it as), you might want to consider rewriting the page that currently handles the form to be a [**Web Service**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx). Then, you can use curl to access that all you want, and rewire your form so everything works as before.

Comment: In theory, yes I could modify the web application to provide a REST or web service interface. I am however reluctant to do so due to the amount of effort involved.

Comment: The effort you spend in refactoring your code to a Web Service would be much less than the headache of figuring and maintaining the exact list of autogenerated __VIEWSTATE code necessary to interact with an ASP.NET form. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786362/using-curl-for-post-data-to-asp-net-page - it's not pretty.

Comment: @jrummell It is rather a matter of economics. Manually entering a few hundred rules can be performed in a day, whereas moving a web service solution through development phases to production (not counting subsequent maintenance) will cost at least a weeks effort.

Comment: If you really want to go down that road, you may end up turning around if you can't get the right `__VIEWSTATE` hash. ASP.NET added that little gem to make it difficult to do exactly what you are attempting. It's somewhat of a security feature.

Comment: "somewhat" is an understatement. Security is a significant feature of __VIEWSTATE.